# Any better alternative instead of SharedPreferences to save/cache much data without online access?

Tags: java, android, caching, sharedpreferences

What’s the best realization of big amount of data storage in mobile memory when there is no online connection? 
Because ino that sharedpreferences can fall down ...

Comment: The use of SQLite databases and other types of files is covered in [the documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data), along with any decent book or course on Android app development.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can store a big amount of data on mobile in a local database like **SQLite, RealM, Room DB.**

For References, you can follow the below links:

**1. SQLite:** 
https://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_sqlite_database.htm

**2. RealM :**
https://www.androidhive.info/2016/05/android-working-with-realm-database-replacing-sqlite-core-data/

**3. Room DB:**
https://medium.com/@tonia.tkachuk/android-app-example-using-room-database-63f7091e69af

Comment: please add ORMlite as well for reference

Answer (score 2):

SQLite for sure. It is fast and you can customize your own functions to access data where you want.

Answer (score 2):

you can use **SQLite database** and save your data as object 
, for easy use you can do that with **room library** , this link for more information:
https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room

Answer (score 0):

As most of the developers suggest and commonly prefer SQLite, with no worries you proceed with SQLite. But it has its own Pros and Cons.

SQLite: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_sqlite_database.htm
SharedPreference: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Altough links may answer the question, it is best to give some information about the solution. Because if the link gets broken in the future. Users who reads them can still understand.